# Cutting out the centre region of a Bitmap and shrinking, in Android

Tags: android, bitmap, android-canvas, android-image

I'm trying to dynamically create images in android by taking an existing Bitmap and removing the centre of it in order to make a "cropped" version. The resulting image's height would naturally be smaller than the original, something like the attached example.

I've got a rough way of doing this by creating two new Bitmaps from the original, one containing the top of the image above the crop section (e.g. the android's head in the example) and the other containing the remaining image below the crop section (the android's feet) using the `Bitmap.createBitmap(source, x, y, width, height)` method, then drawing both of these bitmaps onto a canvas of a size equal to the original image minus the removed space.

This feels a bit clunky, and as I could be calling this method several times a second, it seems wasteful to create two bitmaps each time.

I was wondering if there was a more efficient way of doing this. Something like drawing the original Bitmap onto a canvas using a Path with it's Paint's xfermode set to a 
`new PorterDuffXfermode(Mode.DST_OUT)` in order to cut out the portion of the image I wish to delete. But this seems to clear that area and not shrink the image down i.e. it leaves a big empty gap in the Android's middle.

Any suggestions greatly appreciated!

[image: Example of cutting out centre of bitmap]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why do you create two bitmaps? You only need to create one bitmap and then do canvas.drawBitmap() twice.

```
Bitmap bmpOriginal;
Bitmap bmpDerived = Bitmap.create(...);
Canvas canvas = new Canvas(bmpDerived);
canvas.drawBitmap(bmpOriginal, rectTopSrc, rectTopDst, null);
canvas.drawBitmap(bmpOriginal, rectBottomSrc, rectBottomDst, null);
```

Done.

Comment: How would you be able to remove the centre of the image while only creating one bitmap?
Can you explain your answer with code?

Comment: Ah great, hadn't thought of that. Cheers!